# Get sum of value with inner join mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for terminal

```
Id   status

1   Online 

2   Offline

3   Offline
```

and I have a separate table where I can find the total hours/date of the  up and downtime.

total_time

```
Id  up  down

1   10   14

2   20   4

3   15   9

1   5    19

2   4    20

3  10    14
```

I want to display the terminal id, status and the TOTAL up and downtime(1 = 15(up), 2 = 24(up), 3 = 25(up). I'm using inner join and I have no idea how i will be able to get the sum of the up and downtime..

```
SELECT terminal.Id, terminal.status, total_time.Id, SUM(total_time.up),SUM(total_time.down)
FROM terminal
INNER JOIN total_time
ON terminal.Id = total_time.Id
WHERE terminal.Id = total_time.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick. I am interpreting your question as asking for only the sum of the time of the current status. If this is not what you want (and maybe you want the sum of both times), please let me know.

```
SELECT t.id, t.status, IF(t.status = 'Online', ttlTime.upTime, ttlTime.downTime) as totalTime
FROM terminal t
    JOIN
        (SELECT tt.id, SUM(tt.up) as upTime, SUM(tt.down) AS downTime
        FROM total_time tt
        GROUP BY tt.id) ttlTime ON t.id = ttlTime.id
```

See the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90726/4)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Patrick Q But I want to get the total sum of time..so, in my code, I am only getting the sum of ALL the uptime but I want the sum of time by id

Answer (score 0):

You get "inner sums" by using the `GROUP BY` clause.
Try:

```
SELECT terminal.Id, SUM(total_time.up), SUM(total_time.down)
FROM terminal
INNER JOIN total_time
ON terminal.Id = total_time.Id
GROUP BY terminal.Id
```

Comment: Not quite. It looks like the OP only wants the sum of the time corresponding to the current status.

Comment: Well then just add something like `WHERE terminal.status = 'up'`. Or add terminal.status to the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT terminal.Id, terminal.status, total_time.Id, SUM(total_time.up),SUM(total_time.down)
FROM terminal
INNER JOIN total_time
ON terminal.Id = total_time.Id
```

Should do it. The DISTINCT clause acts as a filter to remove duplicate records from a result set.

Comment: Guess i missed something.